# Simple PHP Code won't work correctly

Tags: php, parsing, parse-error

By first time it seems to be so simple, with no error, but just check it:

```
    1    $c1 = "9515161516516516516156";
    2    $lenght = strlen($c1);
    3    $delimiter = 4;
    4    $с1 = $lenght / $delimiter;
    5    echo $c1;
```

returns

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting
 T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/public_html/test.php on line 4
```

If anyone understands, please answer it.

Comment: You didn't tried to run the code with the line numbers, right?

Comment: Did you accidentally save the file in UTF-8 or so?

Comment: There's no `?` on line 4, I don't see how that error message can come from this code.

Comment: yes i tried, but no change

Comment: there is no answere about encoding @GolezTrol

Comment: Try and rewrite line 4, looks like you got a weird character in there that editors don't pick up.

Comment: Is this all the code in the file?

Comment: When I copied and pasted your example above there seemed to be a null character between `$c` and `1`, Delete the `$c1 =` and retype it manually.

Comment: please try if you have a minute, just for interesting to check what you will got

Comment: Your `c` in `$c1` in line 4 is not an actual `c` but a special character.

Comment: @putvande You are totally right! If you look at the code, the first `$c1` is all black, while on the line 4, `$c1` shows the `1` as red instead. This is just the evidence.

Comment: I was not kidding about that UTF-8 remark.

Comment: Work fine for me, it is likely that you have not put the whole code and it is not possible to reproduce the error, edit your question and put the entire code. Read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's definitely a problem related to encoding/copypaste.

Comment: You using WordPad (windows) or TextEdit (mac)?

Comment: It is a part of a code, i used a simple php redactor

Comment: @KovácsGergely [HOW TO CREATE A MINIMAL, COMPLETE, AND VERIFIABLE EXAMPLE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: **A tip**: Use [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (Window, Mac, Linux) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (Windows) for create your "PHP files"

Answer (score 2):

The `c` in `$c1 = ...` on line four is not the ASCII letter `c`.  It is the Unicode character [`U+0441 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES`](http://codepoints.net/U+0441) which looks exactly like an ordinary `c`.

Delete it from your source file and type in an ordinary `c` instead.